# Need a more efficient way to loop through multiple columns and calculate time difference

Tags: python, nested-loops

Novice Python coder here and I am hoping someone can help me figure out a more efficient way to code this loop. I am trying to calculate the time a product type is in a the field(sales date - beginning of each future month).  I need to repeat this calculation for every month. I have a sales table (with Sales Date) and a financial calendar(list of months).  This code runs well with these small tables, but when I run on a production size table (6000 rows)it takes a long time. Sometimes it wont run at all. I tried different ways of removing the x loop, but nothing worked.

**Code:**

```
s = {'Sales Date':['1/1/2016','1/2/2016','1/3/2016','1/4/2016','2/5/2016']}
a = {'AP Name':['1/1/2018','2/1/2018','3/1/2018','4/1/2019','5/1/2019']}
sales=pd.DataFrame(s)
ap=pd.DataFrame(a)

for y, col_value in enumerate(ap['AP Name']):
  #sales.columns = aplist[y]
  for x,row_value in enumerate(sales['Sales Date']):
    sales.loc[x,y]= pd.to_datetime(ap['AP Name'].iloc[y])- pd.to_datetime(sales['Sales Date'].iloc[x])

sales.head()
```

Comment: There are 2 ways to prevent infinity and hang up. 1) write your code in multiple threads, for example in your outer for loop, for each step, create a thread. I suspect that your code get out of memory because every return value and calculated one, stays in your RAM until your code ends. 2) First calculate your outer for loop  how many cycles it gets, and you can separate your outer code in multiple parts and write each result in separate file.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PierreD updated slightly to allow you to copy/paste and then run.  Hopefully this is what you meant.

Comment: do you really mean to do a full cross product of `s` x `a`?  What are the dimensions? This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do? Are there other fields in your actual tables, and if so, please build a more focused example with input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, the question is essentially about making a cross product between two series of dates, and transform the result into wide format. I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but until further clarifications, here is a way to do specifically what is asked.  Happy to change if additional details come through.

```py
# 1. example setup
sales = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sales Date': ['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/4/2016', '2/5/2016'],
})
ap = pd.DataFrame({
    'AP Name': ['1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', '3/1/2018', '4/1/2019', '5/1/2019'],
})

# 2. transform the strings into actual dates
sales = sales.apply(pd.to_datetime)
ap = ap.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Then:

```py
# cross join (full cartesian product)
z = sales.merge(ap.reset_index(), how='cross')

>>> z
   Sales Date  index    AP Name
0  2016-01-01      0 2018-01-01
1  2016-01-01      1 2018-02-01
2  2016-01-01      2 2018-03-01
3  2016-01-01      3 2019-04-01
4  2016-01-01      4 2019-05-01
5  2016-01-02      0 2018-01-01
6  2016-01-02      1 2018-02-01
7  2016-01-02      2 2018-03-01
8  2016-01-02      3 2019-04-01
 ...
22 2016-02-05      2 2018-03-01
23 2016-02-05      3 2019-04-01
24 2016-02-05      4 2019-05-01
```

Time difference, and pivot to put in wide form:

```py
out = z.assign(tdiff=z['AP Name'] - z['Sales Date']).pivot('Sales Date', 'index', 'tdiff')

>>> out
index             0        1        2         3         4
Sales Date                                               
2016-01-01 731 days 762 days 790 days 1186 days 1216 days
2016-01-02 730 days 761 days 789 days 1185 days 1215 days
2016-01-03 729 days 760 days 788 days 1184 days 1214 days
2016-01-04 728 days 759 days 787 days 1183 days 1213 days
2016-02-05 696 days 727 days 755 days 1151 days 1181 days
```

**Shortcut via numpy broadcasting**

The same result can be obtained with:

```py
out = pd.concat([
    sales,
    pd.DataFrame(
        ap['AP Name'].values[None, :] - sales['Sales Date'].values[:, None],
        index=sales.index
    )], axis=1,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I will try it out.